# Catkin_make not installing Python dependencies

Tags: python, catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do you make `catkin_make` install all Python package dependencies via pip?

I've written a simple Python package with a setup.py file like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from distutils.core import setup
from catkin_pkg.python_setup import generate_distutils_setup
d = generate_distutils_setup(
    version='0.0.1',
    packages=['mypackage'],
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
    install_requires=['somepackage'],
)
setup(**d)
```

And my `CMakeLists.txt` includes `catkin_python_setup()`.

However, when I run `catkin_make` and source `devel/setup.sh`, `somepackage` isn't installed into the virtual environment.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229250/catkin_make-not-installing-python-dependencies/) by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 940 on 2016-03-16

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wouldn't expect catkin_make to do that.

Instead, I'd expect rosdep to do that, however, it doesn't generally. Most python packages are defined in the rosdep distribution files in the form `python-packagename`. So you can add a run dependency on `python-somepackage` into package.xml and let rosdep install the package.

However, not all pip-installable packages are in rosdep's distribution lists. E.g. numpy and scikit-learn are there (as `python-numpy` and `python-sklearn`), but tensorflow is not. When the package is not present, you are, to my best knowledge, out of luck, and have to install it manually (or you can open a Pull request to rosdistro to add the pip package: http://docs.ros.org/independent/api/rosdep/html/contributing_rules.html )

You can verify by issuing

```
rosdep resolve python-somepackage
```

---

Originally posted by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) with karma: 1366 on 2017-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2017-01-26**:
@peci1 you are right. However, if you need a  pip package which is somehow usable for the broader public, simply provide the respective rosdep rule:  http://docs.ros.org/independent/api/rosdep/html/contributing_rules.html

**Comment by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) on 2017-01-26**:
Thanks, I've edited the answer.

**Comment by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) on 2017-01-26**:
This led me to ask on the catkin issue tracker, what's actually the `requires` field doing. The answer is simple: nothing. Do not use it in ROS. I've added a few comments to the documentation, so that people are warned about that. Details here: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdep/issues/497